# SSH agent key is not visible/forwarded to Windows Docker container

Tags: windows, docker, ssh-agent

I am trying to use Windows Docker to build a docker image. When building the docker image, it will invoke pip to access remote private GitHub repositories. However, it always returned this error message: `git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository.` It seems that the SSH agent key is not forwarded to Windows Docker container. I run it in Git Bash Windows.

My device information is:

- Windows Version: Windows11
- Docker Desktop Version: Docker Desktop 4.12.0 (85629)
- WSL2 or Hyper-V backend? WSL2 backend

The main part of the Docker file is:

```
FROM python:3.8.13 as builder
RUN mkdir -p -m 0600 ~/.ssh && ssh-keyscan github.com >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
RUN mkdir -p /home/app/
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r /requirements.txt --target
```

Then, running following commands to build the docker image:

```
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
docker build --ssh default .
```

When running`RUN --mount=type=ssh pip install -r /requirements.txt --target`, the pip needs to access to private GitHub repositories and install them in docker image. But it always returned the permission denied error above - it seems that the ssh agent key is not visible/forwarded in docker container. I actually have already created a SSH key and added it to my GitHub.

I am just wondering if I missed something? Or it may be an underlying issue with Windows Docker? Thank you!

Comment: A docker instance is a cheap-o (lightweight) virtual machine. You choose what gets copied into the VM at the time you create the docker instance. To cause an ssh agent that's running on your real machine to show up in the virtual machine, you must either copy the underlying object that causes forwarding, or else start up yet another forwarder *into* the VM. The latter is probably easier. In all cases you'll need to consult the ssh agent documentation for your host, to find out how to do these things.

Comment: Have you figured it out?

Comment: @galvakojis No, we have not solved it yet.

Answer (score 0):

@yangxiang_li yes, looks like I have figure it out...
first you need a new ssh key without password( or make old one passwordless)

second in your docker-compose.yml  file you need to add this:

```
  your_service:
    ssh:
      - default=../../.ssh/id_rsa
```